# Reverse only vowels in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given a string, I want to reverse only the vowels and leave the remaining string as it is. If input is `fisherman` output should be `fashermin`. I tried the following code:

```py
a=input()
l=[]
for i in a:
    if i in 'aeiou':
        l.append(i)
siz=len(l)-1
for j in range(siz,-1,-1):
    for k in a:
        if k in 'aeiou':
            a.replace(k,'l')
print(a)
```

What changes should be made in this code to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You have few logical mistakes in the code.

- You need to save the o/p of .replace function in another string
  `a= a.replace(k,'l')`
- 'l' is a string. I am sure it was list access that you were going for, so the correct syntax is: `a= a.replace(k,l[j])`
- When replacing if you use the same string(string 'a' in your case), it will lead to all vowels getting replaced by a same vowel.

Using the same variable names, you used, following is one of the correct ways to do it:

```
a=input()
l=""

for i in a:
    if i in 'aeiouAEIOU':
        l+=i
        
new_a = ""
for k in a:
    if k in "aeiouAEIOU":
        new_a += l[-1]
        l = l[:-1]
    else:
        new_a += k
print(a)
print(new_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little easier to turn your word into a list of letters and back:

```
a=input('Enter word: ')
l=[]
for i in a:
    if i in 'aeiou':
        l.append(i)
letters = list(a)
for i in range(len(letters)):
    if letters[i] in 'aeiou':
        letters[i] = l.pop(-1)

print(''.join(letters))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is a piece of code that I have worked on that is the same question.

Write a program to reverse only the vowels in the string.

Example:

Input:
India

Output:
andiI

```
def revv(word):
    a = ''
    b = ''
    for x in word:
        if x in 'aeiouAEIOU':
            a = a+x
            b = b+'-'
        else:
            b = b+x
    c = ''
    d = 0
    a = a[::-1]
    for x in b:
        if x=='-':
            c = c+a[d]
            d = d+1
        else:
            c = c+x
    print(c)

revv('India')
```

> Output:
> andiI

Answer (score 0):

This must work. First found vowels and and indexes of the vowels also you need to store it in a variable. After that you can reverse it easly buy going backword.

```
 a = "fisherman"

 def isVowel(c):
    if c == "a" or c == "e" or c == "u" or c == "i" or c == "o":
        return True
    return False

 def reverseOnlyVowels(string):
    indexes = []
    chars = [] 

    # get vowels and indexes
    for index, i in enumerate(list(string)):
        if isVowel(i):
            indexes.append(index)
            chars.append(i)

    # reverse vowels
     stringList = list(string)
     index1 = 0
     for i, index in zip(chars[::-1], indexes[::-1]):
         stringList[index] = chars[index1]
        index1 += 1
    
    return "".join(stringList)

print(reverseOnlyVowels(a))
```